# How do a make a material continuous on separate objects?

Tags: materials

I am trying to make a puzzle of about 20 individual(seperate) pieces and have a material I made for it be applied across it in a continuous manner. I need the pieces to be an object of their own so that I can move each one independently. However, when I apply the material individually, each piece has the exact same appearance instead of each a part of the appearance I want. I hope I'm making sense. Here is an image as an example of what I mean. The 9 blocks on the left collectively give me the desired continuous appearance. The 9 on the right don't. Each one is a copy of the same pattern. The only way I have been able to have get it to be continuous is by joining the 9 blocks but that won't allow me to move each piece idependently. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: did u try to use object as input for texture coordinate?

Comment: @Chris Dude thank you so much. That was it. Problem solved.

Comment: If you plan on using UV coordinates, you can select multiple objects at once and unwrap them all in the same operation.